# EMC Avamar 7.1 File Level Backup crashing Windows Server 2008 R2 running Jenkins CI

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm in a corporate environment managing 2 Jenkins installations on different Windows Server 2008 R2 VM's. The Jenkins servers are on v1.625.3. Our corporate IT uses EMC Avamar to do file system backups for the entire company.

When the Avamar installation is upgraded to v7.1 of the tool, these servers crash and reboot every night when the backup process runs. They are the only two servers out of hundreds that IT manages with Avamar that have these same symptoms.

There aren't crashes in the Jenkins log to indicate problems there, the VM seems to simply do a hard crash/reboot.